# 1.2 in SQLite3 Database Is Actually 1.199999998

Tags: sql, sqlite, floating-point

I am attempting to store a float in my SQLite3 database using java. When I go to store the number 1.2 in the database, it is actually stored as 1.199999998 & the same occurs for every even number (1.4, 1.6, etc.).

**This makes is really diffult to delete rows because I delete a row according to its version column(whose type =float). So this line wont work:
"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE version=1.2"**

Thats because there is no 1.2 but only 1.19999998. How can I make sure that when I store a float in my SQLite3 DB, that it is the exact number I input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a float if you need precise accuracy. Try a decimal instead.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what the 2 parameters after decimal(param, param) mean? decimal(size, length), I thinks thats what the params mean right? So if I want to store 3 point decimal numbers should I declare a column like so decimal(3, 0) ?

Comment: The parameters to decimal are precision and scale.  Precision defines the TOTAL number of digits stored, scale defines how many of those digits are after the decimal point.

Comment: Exactly what @Alex Deem said. So DECIMAL(4,1) would support 123.4 (four digits total and one after the decimal point) but not 1.234 or 1000.0. For your purpose I would suggest something like DECIMAL(10,5) to cover a wide range of numbers.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support DECIMAL.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the 1.2 you put in your source code or that the user entered into a textbox and ultimately ended up in the database is actually stored as a binary value (usually in a format known as IEEE754).  To understand why this is a problem, try converting 1.2 (1 1/5) to binary by hand (binary .1 is 1/2, .01 is 1/4) and see what you end up with:

> 1.001100110011001100110011001100110011

You can save time by using [this converter](http://www.digitconvert.com/) (ignore the last "1" that breaks the cycle at the site —its because the converter had to round the last digit).

As you can see, it's a repeating pattern.  This goes on pretty much forever.  It would be like trying to represent 1/3 as a decimal.  To get around this problem, most programming languages have a decimal type (as opposed to float or double) that keeps a base 10 representation.  However, calculations done using this type are orders of magnitude slower, and so it's typically reserved for financial transactions and the like.

Answer (score 1):

This is the very nature of floating point numbers.  They are not exact.
I'd suggest you either use an integer, or text field to store a version.

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on the accuracy of a float or a double.  A float should never be used for keys in a data base or to represent money.

You should probably use decimal in this case.

Floats are not an accurate data type.  They are designed to be fast, have a large range of values, and have a small memory footprint.

They are usually implemented using the IEEE standard

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Answer (score 1):

As Joel Coehoorn has pointed out, 1.2 is the recurring fraction 1.0011 0011 0011... in binary and can't be exactly represented in a finite number of bits.

The closest you can get with an IEEE 754 `float` is 1.2000000476837158203125.  The closest you can get with a `double` is 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875.  I don't know where you're getting 1.199999998 from.

Floating-point was designed for representing *approximate* quantities: Physical measurements (a swimming pool is never *exactly* 1.2 meters deep), or irrational-valued functions like `sqrt`, `log`, or `sin`. If you need a value accurate to 15 significant digits, it works fine.  If you truly need an *exact* value, not so much.

For a version number, a more appropriate representation would be a pair of integers: One for the major version and one for the minor version.  This would also correctly handle the sequence 1.0, 1.1, ..., 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, which would sort incorrectly in a `REAL` column.